# Search postcode or town

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I need to search some data depending on whether user enters a postcode or a town. Since the town and the postcode is stored in different columns, how can I distinguish whether it is a postcode or a town and pass it on to query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't see why you'd need to distinguish. Just check both columns.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Postcode = @searchString OR Town = @searchString
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular express sentence to check whether it is a postcode or not, if not, treat it as a town name then.

How to valid a postcode? it depends on what language you are using, here is an example how to valid in PHP:
http://www.ukpostcode.net/validating-uk-postcodes-with-php-wiki-8.html

you can also find the scripts in javascripts and foxpro. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you should get user selection whether he want to search in postcode or a town. If you don't want that then you can run your query in both column one by one. ie search on postcode if found then ok else run on town. or you can join two columns result in one column and search accordingly. although first option is more optimized.

oops i missed or operator. my bad